# Derivative of norm of nonlinear operator with parameter.

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory

I have a nonlinear operator $\mathbf{A}(\theta): X \rightarrow Y$, where $X$, $Y$ are Banach space with $\|\cdot \|_{X}$ and $\|\cdot \|_{Y}$. $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^q$ is the parameter of $\mathbf{A}$. Fixed $\theta$, we can define the operator norm of $\mathbf{A}(\theta)$ as $\|\mathbf{A}(\theta)\|_{\text{op}} = \max\{\sup_{x\neq 0,x\in X}\frac{\|\mathbf{A}(\theta)(x) \|_{Y}}{\|x \|_X} ,\|\mathbf{A}(\theta)(0) \|_{Y}\}$.

Now I have a $\theta^{*}$ which can minimize $\|\mathbf{A}(\theta) \|_{\text{op}}$. In this case, I can compute the derivative of $\|\mathbf{A}(\theta) \|_{\text{op}}$ with respect to $\theta$, set it to zero, and then utilize this equation for some deductions.

Now, my question is that the expression of $\|\mathbf{A}(\theta) \|_{\text{op}}$ involves "$\sup$" and I'm unsure how to differentiate it. Can anyone provide some suggestions?